# UITextView contentOffset changes between viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview

On iOS 8 (I have not tested on iOS 7) I have a `UITextView` that has its text set in the storyboard.  When the view actually appears, the text appears scrolled and I do not want it scrolled.  In fact, I have no idea why anyone would.  Can anyone explain how to change this behavior so it appears scrolled to the top as it should?

This is extremely easy to reproduce:

1. Start a new project
2. Add a `UITextView` with constraints to sticky it to the margins
3. Fill it with more text than will fit in its bounds (helps to increase the font size to something like 36).
4. Run.

It is immediately visually obvious, but if you log what is going on you will see something like the following:

```
2015-03-10 10:34:47.198 ScrollViewTest[61180:2610445] [Inside viewDidLoad] <UITextView: 0x7f9c79851200; frame = (0 0; 600 600); text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit er ...'; clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7f9c78c89df0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9c78c8c220>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {600, 592}>
2015-03-10 10:34:47.288 ScrollViewTest[61180:2610445] [Inside viewDidAppear] <UITextView: 0x7f9c79851200; frame = (0 0; 375 667); text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit er ...'; clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7f9c78c89df0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9c78c8c220>; contentOffset: {0, 457.5}; contentSize: {375, 1176}>
```

Presumably this is because of the `frame` and/or `contentSize` change from the initial load from the storyboard to the actual dimensions it needs to display.

This seems similar to [UITextView contentOffset is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26866500/uitextview-contentoffset-is-set) but the accepted answer to that question does not work.  This is also not solved by setting `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO`.

Comment: Have you tried `[textView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(0,1)];` in the `viewDidAppear:` method?

Comment: Sure, I could also set the `contentOffset` to `{0,0}`. This doesn't really help me, though, because it looks awful to correct it after it has already come into view.  Another issue with this approach is that is forces me to always scroll the textview back up, even if the user is navigating back from another screen.  I don't want the `contentOffset` to be forced to `{0,0}`, I want it to just stay the same as where it was before.

Comment: I should note that I can do the following in `viewWillAppear` but it is a dirty hack and not a true solution: `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [self.messageContentTextView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO]; });`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is that when auto layout is applied, the content offset is mangled. This happens right before `-layoutSubviews` is performed.

So to fix this issue, I could recommend two solutions.

1. Subclass `UITextView` and set `contentOffset` in `-layoutSubviews`.
2. Add `-viewDidLayoutSubviews` to your view controller and set `contentOffset` for any text views there.

Both of these are kind of hacky workarounds, but are better hacky workarounds than `-viewDidAppear:` or `dispatch_async()`.

---

**NOTE**: Take care to ensure you only adjust the `contentOffset` in `-layoutSubviews` or `-viewDidLayoutSubviews` when appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, this helps at least get somewhere acceptable, even if it is not elegant. I've solved this for now by keeping track of whether the view has appeared before and if not, set the `contentOffset` to `{0,0}` in `-viewDidLayoutSubviews`. This could probably be made more robust but is enough for my purposes. I'm also happy not to abuse `dispatchAsync` like I was.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I got rid of that by just adding a 1 line code in `viewDidAppear`

```
[yourTextView setContentOffset: CGPointMake(0,0) animated:NO];
```

You can play with `CGPointMake` as you wish but this worked for me well.
Hope this helps.